# Efficient way on connecting Android to php mysql when internet is slow

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an android app that makes users to login and register. The app uses mysql as database to save users info and does that by connecting through php.

Upon testing the app on a phone I realised it takes too much time logging in a user when using mobile data on a 2G(edge) network but faster when using WLAN

I recently saw that the facebook app "Lite" on their documentation says that it can use 2G networks or even networks with slow connection

My question is that is theres a way to programme the so it can work efficiently even if the network is slow.
Any help or advice will be appreciated

Thanks!!!

Comment: I dont know if you are generating the whole page via PHP and then let it be displayed, but it would certainly help if you just send over the data and let the app render it.

Comment: User enters data into the Android app and the data is posted to the php file which validates the data and does mysql query